# Getting Heroku H10 Error when trying to deploy Strapi, MongoDB Atlas

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, strapi

So I've thoroughly followed the Docs for both Strapi and Heroku (with MongoDb Atlas already connected to Strapi), and I might have missed something important. When I deploy the app, the site loads for a bit then crashes. The `heroku logs --tail` command shows this:

```
2020-05-08T14:41:59.625984+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'findOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-08T14:41:59.626067+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'remove' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-08T14:41:59.626134+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateOne' of module exports inside circular dependency
2020-05-08T14:42:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-08T14:42:29.627137+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-08T14:42:29.626Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-05-08T14:42:29.627879+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-08T14:42:29.627Z] error Error connecting to the Mongo database. Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
2020-05-08T14:42:29.640717+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-05-08T14:42:29.640989+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-05-08T14:42:29.641812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! back-end-4@0.1.0 start: `strapi start`
2020-05-08T14:42:29.641895+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-05-08T14:42:29.641997+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-05-08T14:42:29.642078+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the back-end-4@0.1.0 start script.
2020-05-08T14:42:29.642155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-05-08T14:42:29.649687+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-05-08T14:42:29.649822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-05-08T14:42:29.649879+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-05-08T14_42_29_643Z-debug.log
2020-05-08T14:42:29.758124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2020-05-08T14:42:30.872518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-headland-71392.herokuapp.com request_id=2eb6e39a-875b-4b2c-91cd-3b2bdd914561 fwd="81.128.178.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-08T14:42:31.888706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hidden-headland-71392.herokuapp.com request_id=d96ec78a-83ea-48ca-b576-0ad62d0a15da fwd="81.128.178.133" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My server.json files in all 3 folder, development , production and staging are as follows:

```
{
  "host": "${process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0'}",
  "port": "${process.env.PORT || 1337}",
  "production": true,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": false
  }
}
```

I'm unsure about the Procfile, as it stands its a file in my base directory with no extension but with the line:

```
 web: node strapi start
```

And for reference my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "back-end-4",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {

    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
```

And my `database.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "uri": "${process.env.DATABASE_URI}",
        "database": "${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}"
      },
      "options": {
        "ssl": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you solve it? Can you share the solution? :)

Comment: Hello, I did! Unfortunately it wasn't a specific solution. I just followed the youtube video and docs again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHnRsZwFmR8&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=11&t=0s also, I'm not too sure if it caused this specific problem but I had issues by using the older Strapi docs when following the tutorial; so make sure it's the updated version you are following and using

Comment: I used this video too, but I am not so lucky as you :)  I am wondering did you registered any useeing under Config Vars on Heroku site? Like MONGODB_URL or something like this?

Comment: I do have some config variables, I'm not 100% sure if they actually are doing anything but think I added them at one point when I was struggling just to check I added them. Anyways they were; DATABASE_NAME: MyDbName and DATABASE_URI: MyURI_FromAtlas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW - I had similar issues. I thought I had whitelisted all IPs on Mongodb but hadn't. This step isn't included in the video referenced above and - based on the output logged to your console - I'd guess you're having the same issue.

This setting can be found in Mongodb under Security > Network Access > Add IP Address > If you use `0.0.0.0/0` it will whitelist anything Heroku throws at it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe I had white listed all IPs; I had been following and checking multiple documentation and resources to try and find the error. However, I managed to get a working one just from starting from scratch. Kind of frustrating that the H10 error is so vague that the error can't be narrowed down as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video to deploy your Strapi application with Heroku + MongoDB Atlas

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHnRsZwFmR8&list=PL7Q0DQYATmvhlHxHqfKHsr-zFls2mIVTi&index=11&t=0s

Comment: I already followed this tutorial, with MongoDB Atlas one instead, and still get the H10 error, I might try to replicate it again

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, I had to make sure of three things:

- First, make sure to read the correct documentation. As of now, the Heroku documentation in strapi redirects to the Beta version, and following this tutorial raised all those errors. I had to make sure to follow the current version's documentation.
- Node version. When deploying on Heroku, it automatically installs the latest node version, which might cause a crash. Check your local version, and use the same in your heroku app, by specifying it in the "engines" seciton of your package.json
- missing dependencies. Some modules required by my app were installed and cache on my computer, so it didn't raise any error when starting my app. Unfortunately, I never installed them within my app, and so it raised some errors when trying to deploy. I had to completely remove package-lock.jcon and node_modules, then `npm install`, double check my deployment logs bu using `heroku logs --tail`, to see if there were any missing dependencies left.

After checking all og these, I finally managed to deploy my app.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not using Heroku but I thought I might share my database.json. Maybe you can try it out and see what happens.

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
            "uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase",
        "database": "mydatabase",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "srv": false,
        "port": 27017,
        "username": "myusername",
        "password": "mypassword"
      },
      "options": {
            "ssl": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not too sure it's connection to my DB as such that was the issue, as locally can run it and connect to the cloud DB. I managed to get a working one just from starting from scratch. Kind of frustrating that the H10 error is so vague that the error can't be narrowed down as well

Comment: Did you configure a ecosystem.config.js file?

Comment: I didn't, was not aware this was needed. That being said, my working version I did not have to